# How convert varchar2 to number(15,4) with arithmetic operations in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with VARCHAR2 datatypes and have to create view by casting varchar to number(15,4).But Varchar2 column contains data like `[100 10/50]`, so the expected decimail value is 100.2.
Table

```
CREATE table test1
(   
  id Varchar2(50)  ,
  Least Varchar(50));
```

View:VW_test1

```
CREATE VIEW VW_test1 
    AS 
        (SELECT 
id,
CAST(Least as Number(15,4))
 FROM test1).
```

Can some one tell how to do this conversion.

Comment: I really wonder how one can manage it to create such data content.

Comment: Please provide some more example values. Are they all in format `[100 10/50]`?

Comment: You need to write some code to parse the string. Perhaps using a regular expression to split the string and then do the maths to arrive at the number

Comment: Not all in same format, few are like [12],[-52.23],[58 12/52],[-25 25/50]...etc

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense unless you state explicitly and in full detail a **complete** list of all possible input formats. Do all the inputs, always, include a space and a slash? (Or are some of the numbers in the format `322` with no fraction?) Are the square brackets part of the string? Can there be any other arithmetic operations?

Comment: OK, I see my guess was right already. Can there be any other operations? And are [ ... ]  part of the strings?

Comment: [12],[15.5],[-5],[-5.25],[100 10/50] and [-25 25/50] these are the formats.. no other and all are enclosed with [ ]

Comment: Hi, your title indicates that you are casting a varchar2, yet the body of your post displays casting a varchar (not varchar2).  Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

The solution below identifies one or three substrings that represent numbers (depending on whether there is a space in the input or not). It converts these substrings to numbers, and performs a division and an addition when needed. It also detects whether there is a minus sign and applies it after the other computations are finished.

I didn't cast the end result as NUMBER(15,4) - you can do that too, if needed.

LEAST is the name of an Oracle SQL function, and shouldn't be used as column name.

```
create or replace view vw_test1 as
(
  select id,
         case when instr(least, '-') = 0 then 1 else -1 end
         *
         (
           to_number(regexp_substr(least, '\[-?([^ ]+)( |\])', 1, 1, null, 1))
           + case when instr(least, ' ') = 0 then 0
                  else
                  to_number(regexp_substr(least, ' (.*)/', 1, 1, null, 1))
                     / to_number(regexp_substr(least, '/(.*)]', 1, 1, null, 1))
             end
         ) as least
  from   test1
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the following. Create a function to do the conversion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_convert_op ( v_string VARCHAR2 ) 
        RETURN NUMBER 
IS
        v_op  VARCHAR2(50);
        v_num NUMBER(15,4);
BEGIN
        v_op := TRANSLATE ( v_string,' []', '+');
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '|| 
        v_op                       || 
        ' FROM DUAL' INTO v_num ;
        RETURN v_num;
END;
/
```

Then create your view using the converted values from the function.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_test1 AS
    ( SELECT
        id,
        CAST(fn_convert_op(least) AS NUMBER(15,4) ) least
      FROM
        test1
    );
```

It is recommended that you re-design your table structure to contain proper data.